# How can I pass an eta-reduced generic function as a parameter in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Here is my setup:

```
export interface Promised <d, e> {
    then<o, e>(
        haveData: (data: d) => o,
        haveError?: (error: e) => e
        ): Promised<o, e>;
}
export interface Problem {
    message: string;
}
export interface Nothing {
}
export function ignore<a>(value: a): a { return value; }
export var nothing: Nothing = {};
export function fail<a>(problem: Problem): a;
export function fail<a>(message: string): a;
export function fail(something: any): any {
    if (typeof something === 'string') {
        throw new Error(something);
    } else {
        throw new Error(something.message);
    }
};
```

What I need is the `ignoreOrFail` function as written below:

```
export function ignoreOrFail<d>(promise: Promised<d, Problem>): Nothing {
    promise.then(ignore, fail); // <--- PROBLEM WITH 'fail'
    return nothing;
}
```

However it breaks because the type parameter of the `fail` function cannot be inferred:

```
Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target:
    Call signatures of types 'typeof fail' and '(error: Problem) => Problem' are incompatible:
        Type '{}' is missing property 'message' from type 'Problem'.
        Type '{}' is missing property 'message' from type 'Problem'.
```

This can be fixed if I define another method where the type parameter is hardcoded:

```
export function failAlong(problem: Problem): Problem {
    return fail<Problem>(problem);
};
export function ignoreOrFail<d>(promise: Promised<d, Problem>): Nothing {
    promise.then(echo, failAlong); // <---- WORKS THIS WAY
    return nothing;
}
```

But this is sort of a dumb thing to do, isn't it? What I thought would work is giving the compiler a hint like this:

```
export function ignoreOrFail<d>(promise: Promised<d, Problem>): Nothing {
    promise.then(echo, fail<Problem>);
    return nothing;
}
```

But this seems to be out of syntax. So the question: **is there a way to specify an eta-reduced generic function as a parameter?**
PS:
For non-generic function it is not a question (look at `ignore`).

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you have requested is not supported as shown in the below segment. You can send a request here (http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic)

```
function foo<x>(arg:x){} // foo is x=>x    
function bar(arg:(a:number)=>number){} // arg is number=>number

bar(foo<number>); // Syntax not supported     
bar(foo); // This does work though
```

However you should not get an error in the simple case as shown above. The reason you get an error is because of the type argument `a` as you have already identified.

PS: A simpler reproduction of the problem:

```
declare function foo<x>(arg:number):x; // foo is number=>x    
function bar(arg:(a:number)=>number){} // arg is number=>number    
bar(foo); // FAIL
```